# Default Selected DropdownMenuItem Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

How do i set default selected in DropdownMenuItem?

Because i am still unfamiliar with flutter, i haven't been able to implement code from many answered question here to my code.

In this code there is three option to select, Indonesian, English, and Russian. I want to make dropdown have default selected option when the page show up.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EnamPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EnamPageState createState() => _EnamPageState();
}

class _EnamPageState extends State<EnamPage> {
  Person selectedPerson;
  List<Person> persons = [Person("Indonesian"), Person("English"), Person("Russian")];

  List<DropdownMenuItem> generateItems(List<Person> persons) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem> items = [];
    for (var item in persons) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(item.name),
        value: item,
      ));
    }
    return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: DropdownButton(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: selectedPerson,
                  items: generateItems(persons),
                  onChanged: (item) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedPerson = item;
                    });
                  })),
          Text((selectedPerson != null)
              ? selectedPerson.name
              : "Silakan Pilih")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Person {
  String name;
  Person(this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your "selectedPerson" to the value you want in the initState() call (this is where you pre-define values before widget's first render):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EnamPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EnamPageState createState() => _EnamPageState();
}

class _EnamPageState extends State<EnamPage> {
  List<Person> persons = [Person("Indonesian"), Person("English"), Person("Russian")];
  Person selectedPerson;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedPerson = persons.first; // Set to the first Person
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem> generateItems(List<Person> persons) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem> items = [];
    for (var item in persons) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(item.name),
        value: item,
      ));
    }
    return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: DropdownButton(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: selectedPerson,
                  items: generateItems(persons),
                  onChanged: (item) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedPerson = item;
                    });
                  })),
          Text((selectedPerson != null)
              ? selectedPerson.name
              : "Silakan Pilih")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Person {
  String name;
  Person(this.name);
}
```

Comment: its work too but my rep < 15, i cant vote your answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Deny Ocr from Flutter Indonesia, Telegram Group

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EnamPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EnamPageState createState() => _EnamPageState();
}

class _EnamPageState extends State<EnamPage> {
  Person initialPersonValue = Person("Indonesian");
  Person selectedPerson;
  List<Person> persons = [
    Person("Indonesian"),
    Person("English"),
    Person("Brazillian"),
  ];

  getSelectedPerson() {
    var currentPerson = persons
        .where((person) => person.name == initialPersonValue.name)
        .toList();
    return currentPerson[0];
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem> generateItems(List<Person> persons) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem> items = [];
    for (var item in persons) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(item.name),
        value: item,
      ));
    }
    return items;
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: DropdownButton(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: getSelectedPerson(),
                  items: generateItems(persons),
                  onChanged: (item) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedPerson = item;
                    });
                  })),
          Text((selectedPerson != null) ? selectedPerson.name : "Silakan Pilih")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Person {
  final String name;
  Person(this.name);
}
```